# Get userId in invisible input text field of a form

Tags: forms, session, odoo, odoo-10

Relatively new to Odoo. I needed to save user id of **currently logged in user** in the form "email" and input as shown:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="userid" />
```

Comment: Removed tags from title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are trying on website form try this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="userid" t-att-value="request.uid"/>
```

or we can get it from session

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="userid" t-att-value="request.session.uid"/>
```